# Get all elements of the current window

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I need to modify the DOM of a page but can not find how to get the elements of the current window.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var bot = document.getElementById('bot');
  bot.style.cursor = "pointer";
  bot.addEventListener('click',function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({
      currentWindow: true,
      active: true
    }, function(tab)  {
      // tab[0] <----- I need to get the elements of the current window to modify
      // for example document.getElementById('element')
    });
  });        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the code you showed runs in a popup.

To access DOM of a page open in an existing tab, you need [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

See this [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) as the first step.

For a concrete example, given a tab ID, you can inject a script and get a single value back (as a simplest solution) like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"}, function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

And the content script:

```
// Simplest possible DOM operation
return document.getElementById('element').value;
```

For more advanced usage, see the documentation link above and [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation.

Comment: thanks for u response! I understand everything you said does not work  `console.log(result)` returns undefined.. :(